# python function arguments in openerp

Tags: python, odoo

Can anyone explain to me what those arguments stand for and what they do **(self, cr, uid, obj, name, type, args, context)**. I was not able to find any good documentation about them.

```
def _do_something(self, cr, uid, obj, name, type, args, context=None):
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [6.0 method docs](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/methods.html) -

> *cr* – database cursor
>
> *uid* - current user id
>
> *context* – context arguments, like lang, time zone

from the [6.0 field_type docs](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html) -

> *obj* is the same as self
>
> *name* receives the field name
>
> *args* is a list of 3-part tuples containing search criteria for this field, although the search function may be called separately for each tuple.

Answer (score 1):

there are required arguments in OpenERP for most of the functions which are **self, cr, uid, ids, context**

1. self: Self is your current object.
2. cr: It is a cursor for your postgress database which is connected to OpenERP
3. uid: It contains **ID** of current logged in user.
4. ids: List of IDs of your records.
5. context: A dictionary with some keys and values like lang, time zone, etc.

If you are defining a function for `fields.function`, there are some extra arguments are required. You can refer [Functional Fields](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html#functional-fields).